# Spring decide bean during runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-ioc

I have multiple provider classes (`Provider1` and `Provider2`), how do I decide what bean I use depending on the input parameter in the `Processor` class?

```
public class Processor{
    private Provider provider;

    public void process(String  providerName) throws Exception {
        // What should I do here to invoke either provider1 or provider2 depending on the providerName?
        provider.doOperation();
    }
}

public class Provider1  {
    public void doOperation(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        //Code
    }
}

public class Provider2  {
    public void doOperation(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        //Code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about somthing like this?

1# into your processor class :

```
public class Processor{

    private Map<Provider> providers;

    public void process(String providerName) throws Exception {
        Provider provider = providers.get(providerName);
        provider.doOperation();
    }
}
```

2# in your spring config:

```
<bean id="provider1" class="xx.yy.zz.Provider1"/>
<bean id="provider2" class="xx.yy.zz.Provider2"/>

<bean id="processor" class="xx.yy.zz.Processor">

  <property name="providers">
    <map>
        <entry key="provider1" value-ref="provider1" />
        <entry key="provider2" value-ref="provider2" />
    </map>
  </property>

</bean>
```

now  for example if you call `processor.process("provider1")` it will call `provider1.doOperation()`

Answer (score 0):

This is the case of `Factory pattern`. You can create a (`ProviderFactory`) class, register all the providers and get provider based on value, e.g.:

```
class ProviderFactory(){

    private List<Provider> providers = new ArrayList<>();

    public Provider getProvider(String input){

        if(input.equals("test1")){
            //Find based on criteria
            return provider1;
        }else if(input.equals("test2")){
            //Find based on criteria
            return provider2;
        }
    }

    public void registerProvider(Provider provider){
        providers.add(provider);
    }
}
```

You can call `registerProvider` method on application startup and add as many providers as you want. Once that is initialised, you can call `getProvider` method and return appropriate instance based on some criteria.

Please note that `providers` doesn't necessarily need to be a `list`, it can be any data structure. It depends on which structure suits your criteria the best.

[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm)'s documentation/more examples for Factory pattern.